Wrong solution to a short RISC-V exercise
We are told that a RISC-V exercise with no data forwarding executes the instruction add x3,x2,x1, followed by sw x3, 16(x8). My answer was the following:
                |    1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
add x3,x2,x1    |   IF  ID  EX  ME  WB
sw x3, 16(x8)   |       IF  ID  EX  --  ME  WB

With the following reasoning: the first row being obvious, the sw instruction needs the correct content of the x3 register to know in which memory address to store the value (ME), hence it needs for the first instruction to WB the result into the x3 register i.e. we need to wait until the WB of the first row to move on to the ME of the second row. The correct answer, however, is this:
                |    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
add x3,x2,x1    |   IF  ID  EX  ME  WB
sw x3, 16(x8)   |               IF  ID  EX  --  ME  WB

I do not even understand why the second IF can't run right after the first. Why is this the case? Why are my answer and reasoning wrong?

do you have to wait for completion of WB?
We are told that a RISC-V exercise with no data forwarding executes the
instruction add x3,x2,x1, followed by sw x3, 16(x8).

My answer was the following:

                |    1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
add x3,x2,x1    |   IF  ID  EX  ME  WB
sw x3, 16(x8)   |       IF  ID  EX  --  ME  WB

With the following reasoning: the first row being obvious, the sw instruction
needs the correct content of the x3 register to know in which memory address to
store the value (ME), hence it needs for the first instruction to WB the result
into the x3 register i.e. we need to wait until the WB of the first row to move
on to the ME of the second row. 

There's a subtle consideration that you may have missed. (Or that I'm missing.) Let's take a close look at the register file:

This is usually implemented such that if RD WRITE ADDR has the same value as RS1 READ ADDR or RS2 READ ADDR, then RD WRITE DATA will be gated to the appropriate output, either RS1 READ DATA or RS2 READ DATA, instead of the internally held value that is being over-written in this clock cycle.
Here's an example, in verilog, that shows this specific testing taking place to achieve this result:

So this means you do not have to wait out the WB cycle of the prior instruction. When WB is transmitting both the resulting register address and also its value to the register file, the register file is perfectly able to recognize that data being written to a register is also being requested by a later instruction and can make it available at its output.
That's pretty much the standard.
On the other hand, it's possible to forward from ME. It's even possible to forward from EX, as well. So if full forwarding is enabled (from both ME and also from EX) then no stalls are required, at all.
the "correct" answer?
The correct answer, however, is this:

                |    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
add x3,x2,x1    |   IF  ID  EX  ME  WB
sw x3, 16(x8)   |               IF  ID  EX  --  ME  WB

I do not even understand why the second IF can't run right after the first.
Why is this the case? Why are my answer and reasoning wrong?

Well, I've no idea why that was shown as the correct answer. It's just simply not the correct answer. It can't be.
The IF must occur or else there is no way for the hazard detection unit to detect a hazard! So I don't know who produced that result. But they weren't thinking well at the time.
stop for now
I wrote in comments that I believe the correct answer, without forwarding, should be:

I'm going to stop here and see how you respond to the above. If it turns out that you can use more detail (specific details about each stage) then perhaps I can help a little more. But right now both your answer and also theirs are wrong. We need to first get onto the same page before much more can be adduced into the conversation.

Without data forwarding, the sw instruction cannot proceed to its ID stage (which reads x3) until x3 is updated in the add instruction’s WB stage. With your first answer, your schedule starts sw too early. Hence, it must wait to fetch until x3 is written back, so the sw instruction’s IF cannot run right after the add but must be delayed until x3 is available.

Right! It is in the ID stage that x3 is read. However, I continue not to understand why the second IF can't happen at the second clock cycle.

@Sam Without forwarding enabled it should look like this. So yes, the IF of the 2nd instruction can, as you say, take place on cycle 2.

IF can't be delayed based on the access, because until IF has happened, the processor can't know if the sw will access x3 at all. It has to be the stall in between IF and ID as periblepsis says.
